# Rake Aborted, Gemfiles requires a different rake

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql-5.7

I am completing the tutorial Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training through Lynda.com on Windows 7 (64 bits) using MySQL Server 5.7(64bits), MySQL Connector C 6.1 6.1.2 (32bits), Ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32] and Rails 3.2.12.

In the training, I am in the section on "Databases and Migrations" attempting to sync the database I have created in MySQL with my Rails project, however I have been running into an abort message.

The instructor asked my class to go through Command Prompt to open up our rails project and perform a Rake to build a "schema.rb" with this code:

This is what it says now when I run "db:schema:dump"

`C:\Sites\todo>rake db:schema:dump rake aborted!`

`You have already activated rake 10.1.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.3.`

`Using bundle exec may solve this.`

`C:/Sites/todo/config/boot.rb:6:in`'`

`C:/Sites/todo/config/application.rb:1:in`'`

`C:/Sites/todo/Rakefile:4:in`'`

`(See full trace by running task with --trace)`

What do I do to get the rake that the Gemfile needs?

Comment: Try `bundle install` before

Answer (score 5):

So active gem  version 10.1.1, but your project have dependency 10.0.3

To solve just use `bundle exec` before  `rake db:schema:dump`

`bundle exec rake db:schema:dump`

As you have older version at Gemfile, you  can do `gem uninstall rake`, `bundle install`, this will install proper version of `rake`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, I decided to delete Windows off of my computer and download a Linux distribution called Ubuntu. This completely bypassed the issue by changing the programming environment I was in and thereby accelerated me in a programming environment suitable to perform in Ruby. I didn't have to spend any money on a new computer, but I did lose about 3 months time waiting to get an answer to this question.